# 'FIles are Empty' error when uploading files on Strapi Media Library which connects to AWS S3 Bucket upload provider

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, strapi

I am facing an issue with strapi upload provider.
I have connected strapi with aws upload provider s3 bucket, and deployed it to production.

Untill 2 days ago I was able to upload images from strapi normally and see them getting saved in AWS. But since yesterday Im getting 'Files are empty' Error every time Im trying to upload something from production.

(If I try to upload locally from localhost, everything works fine and the image is uploaded in AWS, so this is a PROD specific issue)

Can somebody help here? Where is this issue comming from ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I confirm axios > 0.27.2 breaks the file upload. I had axios@1.1.3 installed and reverting to 0.27.2 fixed the issue.

You can try axios 1.2 too I think
https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/5224

Comment: Any idea how we would be able to use the latest version of Axios with Strapi? This somehow feels a bit weird to me, that an update to the axios core would result in a non working media library within Strapi...